Ubuntu 22.04 LTS 6.5.0-27 missing displays
After a routine software update using sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade, external monitors are no longer detected.
Ubuntu is running on a Lenovo E15 laptop with an AMD CPU and integrated graphics.
The following updates have been made:
2024-04-08 09:23:50 upgrade linux-generic-hwe-22.04:amd64 6.5.0.26.26~22.04.13 6.5.0.27.28~22.04.1
2024-04-08 09:23:50 upgrade linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04:amd64 6.5.0.26.26~22.04.13 6.5.0.27.28~22.04.1
2024-04-08 09:23:55 upgrade linux-headers-generic-hwe-22.04:amd64 6.5.0.26.26~22.04.13 6.5.0.27.28~22.04.1
2024-04-08 09:23:59 upgrade linux-headers-generic:amd64 5.15.0.101.98 5.15.0.102.99
2024-04-08 09:23:59 upgrade linux-libc-dev:amd64 5.15.0-101.111 5.15.0-102.112
2024-04-08 09:23:59 upgrade xserver-common:all 2:21.1.4-2ubuntu1.7~22.04.8 2:21.1.4-2ubuntu1.7~22.04.9
2024-04-08 09:23:59 upgrade xserver-xephyr:amd64 2:21.1.4-2ubuntu1.7~22.04.8 2:21.1.4-2ubuntu1.7~22.04.9
2024-04-08 09:24:00 upgrade xserver-xorg-legacy:amd64 2:21.1.4-2ubuntu1.7~22.04.8 2:21.1.4-2ubuntu1.7~22.04.9
2024-04-08 09:24:00 upgrade xserver-xorg-core:amd64 2:21.1.4-2ubuntu1.7~22.04.8 2:21.1.4-2ubuntu1.7~22.04.9
2024-04-08 09:24:00 upgrade xwayland:amd64 2:22.1.1-1ubuntu0.11 2:22.1.1-1ubuntu0.12

The display manager is X11 GDM3.
The laptop screen is the only one that still works.
It's listed as "unknown display" in the display settings.
The monitor has a refresh rate of 60Hz, but the settings show 77Hz.
The settings cannot be changed either (e.g. brightness, resolution, refresh rate).
Does anyone have any idea what the problem might be with kernel 6.5.0-27?
Temporary solution: Boot Ubuntu with the previous installed kernel (6.5.0-26 in my case).

External monitors work as normal
Display settings show correct values
Display settings can be changed


Same issue. Also booted to 26.
